# Python Rock, Paper, Scissors (Not showing Draw)

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python code for a player vs comp. Rock, Paper , Scissor game.

After playing it a few time i found it was never drawing.

It was either win or losing

My guess is i have made an error in the conditions part

Solution with explanation would be appreciated

```
import random

while True:

  print("Enter player \n 1. Rock \n 2. paper \n 3. scissor")    
  game_dict = {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}
  player = int(input("Enter 1, 2, 3: "))

  while player > 3 or player < 1:
      player = int(input("Please enter a valid number: "))

  comp = random.randint(1, 3)
  while comp == player:
      comp = random.randint(1, 3)

  if comp == 1: 
      comp_choice_name = 'Rock'
  elif comp == 2: 
      comp_choice_name = 'paper'
  else: 
      comp_choice_name = 'scissor'
      
  print(f"Computer choice is: {comp_choice_name}" ) 

  a = game_dict.get(player)
  b = game_dict.get(comp)
  dif = a - b
 
  # Bug must be around here
  if dif in [-1, 2]:
      print('Player Wins.')
  elif dif in [-2, 1]:
      print('Comp Wins.')
  else:
      print('Draw, Please continue.')

  ans = input("Do you wanna play again? (Y/N): ")
  if ans == "N" or ans == "n":
      break    

print("Thanks for playing")
```

Comment: Because you are changing the computer's choice as long as it is similar to the player's... `while comp == player: comp = random.randint(1, 3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening for the 13th and 14th line.

```
while comp == player:
    comp = random.randint(1,3)
```

For this, even if it's a draw, the integer for comp gets changed as long comp and player doesn't have different values. Resulting, in either win or loose.

Remove this lines, that should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It was not drawing the match because you have made the code in such a way that if the value given by player and the value given by computer matches computer will restart the random function to not match the value of "comp" and "player".
If you player choose 1
and comp also choose 1
then the function  will reinitiated to get the value other than 1.

have a look on this part of your code.

```
  comp = random.randint(1, 3)
  while comp == player:  # you are recalling the same function until the value of 'player'is equal to 'comp'
      comp = random.randint(1, 3)
```

You just need to delete this while loop from the code.

HERE IS THE FINAL CODE:-

```
import random

while True:
    
      print("Enter player \n 1. Rock \n 2. paper \n 3. scissor")    
      game_dict = {1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}
      player = int(input("Enter 1, 2, 3: "))
    
      while player > 3 or player < 1:
          player = int(input("Please enter a valid number: "))
    
      comp = random.randint(1, 3)
      # while comp == player:    # I just comment out this two lines
      #     comp = random.randint(1, 3)
    
      if comp == 1: 
          comp_choice_name = 'Rock'
      elif comp == 2: 
          comp_choice_name = 'paper'
      else: 
          comp_choice_name = 'scissor'
          
      print(f"Computer choice is: {comp_choice_name}" ) 
    
      a = game_dict.get(player)
      b = game_dict.get(comp)
      dif = a - b
     
      # Bug must be around here
      if dif in [-1, 2]:
          print('Player Wins.')
      elif dif in [-2, 1]:
          print('Comp Wins.')
      else:
          print('Draw, Please continue.')
    
      ans = input("Do you wanna play again? (Y/N): ")
      if ans == "N" or ans == "n":
          break    
    
print("Thanks for playing")
```